# How to combine these two queries into a single one?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two queries that effectively use the same data. I am trying to combine them into one, so I can save space but I am having problems. **I am trying to SELECT from the second query. I will demonstrate in my attempt.**

Query A:

```
SELECT TOP 5 ([Parent]), [Game ID] 
FROM Games 
WHERE [Parent] = 'Zelda' 
ORDER BY [Game ID] DESC;
```

Query B:

```
SELECT QueryA.[Parent], QueryA.[Game ID] 
FROM QueryA 
WHERE Mid(QueryA.[Game ID], 5) NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(Mid(Game.[Game ID], 5)) 
    FROM Game
);
```

Separately, these queries work, but it seems like this can be combined into a single query. I am trying to figure out how. I thought I could just do something like

```
SELECT QueryA.[Parent], QueryA.[Game ID] 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5 ([Parent]), [Game ID] 
    FROM Games 
    WHERE [Parent] = 'Zelda' 
    ORDER BY [Game ID] DESC
) 
WHERE Mid(QueryA.[Game ID], 5) NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(Mid(Game.[Game ID], 5)) 
    FROM Game
);
```

But that's not the case. Seems basic, but I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Why do you need two queries. Can you just add your `WHERE` condition of your outer query into the inner query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be that you forget the alias name for your subquery. Try this:

```
SELECT QueryA.[Parent],
       QueryA.[Game ID]
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 5 ([Parent]), [Game ID]
     FROM Games
     WHERE [Parent] = 'Zelda'
     ORDER BY [Game ID] DESC) as QueryA
WHERE Mid(QueryA.[Game ID], 5) NOT IN
        (SELECT MAX(Mid(Game.[Game ID], 5))
         FROM Game);
```

And if this is not the solution, is happening some error that you could show?